# CKeditor - Edit form doesn't show anything in a <code> tag

Tags: 7, wysiwyg

Using ckeditor module + ckeditor 3.6.

I am using the 'full' text format as a admin role and when I initially fill out a text area and use the 'font styles' dropbar to make the text into 'code' html tags I can see everything great. When I save it, it comes out just like I wanted to.

But if I go back and edit the node (say a article node) I am not able to see any of the text that is between the code tags in the editor. When I click on 'plain text' format, I can see the code tags + text just fine.

If I save it with the 'full' format and I can't see the text in the editor, it still comes out fine on the page view. What could be the reason I can't see anything in 'code' tags in the edit form? All other ckeditor 'font styles' work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a issue with the CKeditor module it appears. If I use the styles dropdown menu for 'Computer Code' save it and then edit it, the text will disappear in the editor. If I disable the editor, I can see the code tags again.

I removed the CKeditor module and enabled and configured the wysiwyg module and now there is no issue. The text in between the code tags appear in the editor just fine now.

Answer (score 1):

The `<code>`tag is probably stripped because it's not an allowed HTML tag. Please check the properties of your input format in `admin/config/content/formats` and check that `Limit allowed HTML tags`is unchecked.

Comment: I am using the Full HTML text format, 'Limit allowed HTML tags' is unchecked.

Comment: It appears to be a issue with the CKeditor module itself. After I disabled the module and enabled the wysiwyg module, I can see the text.